# Mailbox Full bounce for an Exchange Distribution List

Tags: exchange-2003, email-bounces, distribution-lists

This is neat.  Just got this in a shared Exchange 2003 mailbox:

```
Your message did not reach some or all of the intended recipients.

      Subject:  [real subject replaced]
      Sent: 9/16/2009 1:35 PM

The following recipient(s) could not be reached:

      [real dist list name replaced] on 9/16/2009 1:36 PM
            The message could not be delivered because the recipient's mailbox is full.
            <exchangeserver.mydomain.com #5.2.2>
```

My thought is that someone entered the distribution list in the To: field of a new message (Outlook 2003 here) but didn't click the + to expand the distribution list into individual recipients.  Then when one of the recipients' mailbox was full the bounce message was created with the distribution list name instead of the recipient's name.

Anyone ever see this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this before on my Exchange 2k3 server, and came to similar conclusions that it was one of the members of the DL that had a full mailbox, but the failure message came from the DL rather than the individual.

It was a while back, so I can't remember the details, but I think I tested the theory (creating a new DL with a single user in who's mailbox was full, and then not full) and it turned out to be correct.